# Android camera parameter IsVideoSnapshotSupported incorrectly set to false

Tags: android, video, xamarin, camera

When I check the device camera parameter IsVideoSnapshotSupported, it is set to false despite my device seemingly supporting this functionality. This setting is used to detect if a photo can be taken while the device is recording a video. My device can natively do this, and I can successfully take a photo while recording within my app if I just ignore the IsVideoSnapshotSupported value.

I don't like the idea of blindly assuming the feature is supported by all devices using my app, but I am not able to determine why the value of this parameter is false. The only device I have tested is a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android version 5.0.1. The application is being built using Xamarin. The app is built on API 15.

Comment: Since you are using api 21 and Camera.Parameters is deprecated, have you tried android.hardware.camera2's Metadata to see if the device's CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT_VIDEO_SNAPSHOT is reported correctly? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT_VIDEO_SNAPSHOT & http://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Hardware.Camera2/

Comment: I am not able to use API 21 at this time. I need to support all the way back API 15. I should have mentioned this in my original post - I will edit it and add this information. Your idea is good, but I'm not in a position to bump up the API level of the app at this time.

Comment: I thought maybe you could at least try it to see if it reported the same way. Also I would add the video snapshot capability to an Xam' Insight event and run it on their test cloud to see how many devices report true/false as a quick test...