# Taking picture while recording video on Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I have written the Android service shown below for recording the front cam in the background. This works very well. But now I would like to also take a picture every 5 seconds while recording. Is this somehow possible? When I try to open a second camera (in another service) I'm getting an error.

```
public class RecorderService extends Service implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private Camera camera = null;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Create new SurfaceView, set its size to 1x1, move it to the top left corner and set this service as a callback
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                1, 1,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                //.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Background Video Recorder")
                .setContentText("")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        startForeground(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID_RECORDER_SERVICE, notification);
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    // Method called right after Surface created (initializing and starting MediaRecorder)
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        camera = Camera.open(1);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        camera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));

        FileUtil.createDir("/storage/emulated/0/Study/Camera");
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/storage/emulated/0/Study/Camera/" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".mp4");

        try { mediaRecorder.prepare(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        mediaRecorder.start();

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Runnable runnable = new PictureThread(camera);
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    // Stop recording and remove SurfaceView
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();

        camera.lock();
        camera.release();

        windowManager.removeView(surfaceView);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }
}
```

**Edit**: I have now written a thread `PictureThread`. This thread is started from `RecorderService` and tries to take a picture while video recording.

```
public class PictureThread implements Runnable {
    private final static String TAG = PictureThread.class.getSimpleName();

    private Camera camera;

    PictureThread(Camera camera) {
        this.camera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }

    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
        }
    };

    Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        }
    };

    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };
}
```

Unfortunately `jpegCallback` gets never called (i.e. the Log message is never printed). When I open the camera app of my tablet then I can take pictures while video recording, so this should be possible.

I have also tried the Camera2 API example as suggested by Alex Cohn (https://github.com/mobapptuts/android_camera2_api_video_app). Recording a video works and also taking a picture works but when I try to take a picture while recording, no picture is created (but also no error). Nevertheless, I have found this example app not working very reliable (perhaps there is another example app).

**Edit 2**: The `shutterCallback` and `rawCallback` of `takePicture` gets called but the data of the `rawCallback` is null. The `jpegCallback` gets never called.. Any idea why and how this can be solved? I have also tried to wait in the thread for a period of time to give the callback time for being called and I have tried to make the callbacks static in my main activity (so that it gets not garbage collected). Nothing worked.

Comment: Data on rawCallback is null even without recording. In the last 10 years I didn't see one device that delivered meaningful data on this callback. As for jpegCallback, what makes you believe that it should work?

Comment: @AlexCohn Why should the jpegCallback not work? Did I make a mistake? With the Android stock camera app I can take pictures while recording so I believe it should work...

Comment: Which device is that?

Comment: @AlexCohn It is a Huawei MediaPad M2 tablet (10").

Comment: Have you tried [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera)?

Comment: I bet the built-in camera app uses camera2 API. BTW, you can learn a lot if you disassemble it.

Comment: @AlexCohn I have now tried Open Camera. When I switch from video recording to taking a picture the video recording is stopped and the video is stored. I think the app does not support taking a picture while recording.

Comment: @AlexCohn But the camera2 API project you linked did not work on my tablet... Is there perhaps another one available with free source code?

Comment: @AlexCohn It turned out that when I do Camera.unlock() then the jpegCallback is never called, otherwise it gets called. But for recording video I have to call Camera.unlock() first...

Comment: You can start with the official sample apps, but I don't think they demo how jpeg and video can be captured simultaneously https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:**

With the clarification:

The old camera API supports calling takePicture() while video is being recorded, if [Camera.Parameters.isVideoSnapshotSupported](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#isVideoSnapshotSupported()) reports true on the device is question.

Just hold on to the same camera instance you're passing into the MediaRecorder, and call Camera.takePicture() on it.

Camera2 also supports this with more flexibility, by creating a session with preview, recording, and JPEG outputs at the same time.

**Original answer:**

If you mean taking pictures with the back camera, while recording with the front camera - that's device-dependent.  Some devices have enough hardware resources to run multiple cameras at once, but most won't (they share processing hardware between the two cameras).

The only way to tell if multiple cameras can be used at once is to try opening a second camera when one is already open.  If it works, you should be good to go; if not, that device doesn't support multiple cameras at once.

Comment: I want to record video from the front camera and at the same time taking picture from the front cam.

Comment: I have made an edit to my original post. Using Camera.takePicture() did not work although my device should be able to capture pictures while recording.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot open separate camera instances for video recording and stills capture. The deprecated Camera API is not reliable for such tasks (see e.g. *[Android camera parameter IsVideoSnapshotSupported incorrectly set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33225203/192373)* about Samsung S4).

You can use **camera2** API (on devices that support such mode) to capture different formats and resolutions from the same camera instance. Here is a video tutorial: https://www.nigeapptuts.com/android-video-app-still-capture-recording/

Comment: camera2 API sounds interesting. If I understand you correctly, I can create a camera instance and then using this instance to both recording video from the front cam and at the same time taking pictures from the front cam. Could you provide some code example how this could be achieved? That would be very nice.

Comment: I have made an edit to my original post with my new approach.

Comment: Thank you, I have found a example repository with a project through your answer! https://github.com/mobapptuts/android_camera2_api_video_app You very helped to me!