# How to Take a Photo During WebRTC Call in Android

Tags: android, webrtc, android-camera2

**Use Case**

During a WebRTC call between User A and User B, User B needs to be able to take take a high-resolution photo of User A using the camera that is currently attached to the PeerConnection.

**Solutions Tried**

- I have tried adding a new video renderer with a custom VideoRenderer.Callbacks.

  ```
  public void renderFrame(VideoRenderer.I420Frame i420Frame) {
      //Convert i420Frame to YuvImage
  }
  ```

There are two problems that I ran into with this approach is that when my renderFrame function gets called, the camera feed breaks. The other problem is that i420Frame.yuvStrides is null.

- I have tried to use the Camera2 API to take a photo. This means that I dispose the local media stream. Create a new cameraDevice using the CameraManager. Create a session/request. Try to take the photo. And then re-create the local media stream.

I don't like this solution, but I wanted a proof-of-concept. However, with the threading that is going on inside of the WebRTC libraries, I don't have a way of knowing when the local MediaStream finally disconnects the camera. I don't have too much experience with Camera2, so I could be doing something wrong.

**TL;DR**

I'm looking for the proper way to get access to a high-resolution still from a camera that is currently being used in a WebRTC MediaStream.

Comment: Note that it be impossible on many devices

Comment: Can you elaborate on what would make it _impossible_? I get unreasonably difficult, but why impossible?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334646/192373. Quite often, IsVideoSnapshotSupported capability is not available