# I want to capture a still image while a video is being recorded in android using Camera2 api

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using camera2 api to interface the camera. A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331320/taking-picture-while-recording-video-on-android) thoroughly. However, the camera that I am using has Hardware Legacy Support. According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice) , I cannot use the `TEMPLATE_VIDEO_SNAPSHOT` feature. One solution is to stop the video recording when I want to capture a still image and use `TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE` and then again start the video recording. But this solution will create multiple video files and does not seems a good method.

Can anyone suggest a better way of capturing images while recording a video?

Answer (score 1):

For legacy devices there is no proper solution.

One thing you could try is to [get a bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView#getBitmap(int,%20int)) from the TextureView used by the camera preview. This is not optimal at all, as you are actually getting a screenshot of what is being displayed on screen, which is low quality/size, and in addition needs to be performed with caution to not introduce a lag into the recording.

The idea of stopping the recording, take a photo, and start a new the recording, will not work, as such operation will require too much time. Adding the problem that as you know, you will end up with multiple videos that need to be merged.

As a side note, is there a reason why you wish to implement such feature in legacy devices? Consider that any solution you implement will be only for users with old devices, and in fact will be **a temporary solution with an end date** not used at all after a few years, while people keep on getting newer phones where they have such capability, which now days have even the cheapest new phones.